How to create a extruded 4-star shape that is rotated inwards?
I recently made a logo in figma, which I would like to further enhance in Blender. I'm thinking of a Geometry Node Setup, in which I can modify the thickness non-destructively and maybe include a nice spin/screw animation in there.
Should I use a curve for the node setup? Or does it make more sense to start with a mesh?
I'm thinking of using like a 1/4 of the shape and maybe screw it along the center point of origin, but that doesn't look good so far.
Thanks for your guidance!


Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/99355/how-to-create-a-ribbon-wrapped-sphere

Thank you for your suggestion, I now tried to describe the shape in the title.

The main problem here is that a cyclic curve automatically interpolates the tilt between its start and end. So instead I bevel the curve first, and then split at the same spot where the radial gradient has a seam. Still, I have two overlapping edge loops on $y=0; x<0$, each sampling the gradient texture exactly on its seam - so I mix the position a little bit with a face position to move away from that seam. You could instead make/reuse a check, and in this case set the position to a switch between $<-1, 0, 0>$ and $<1, 0, 0>$ vectors depending on the face's $y$ sign.

I've set the integer to $3$ above, but multiples of $4$ give a more symmetric result:

I forgot to add "Merge by Distance" which is important for perfect shading:

You can offset the gradient:

Alternate:

Or like in your reference, limit to certain areas:


This is seriously amazing, thanks for your setup! Personally I used 0.575m for the Fillet Curve, Free Handle Type, Quadrilateral of 0.4m an a map range from 0.1 to 0.9 to get closer to the Figma Design, but without you this would be impossible for me!
